# Edit Custom Post Type on Custom Admin Page instead Post Admin

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, forms, options

Background:
I am still quite fresh to coding and WordPress. For me the best way to understand, is to work on a specific project.

**Project:** I want to build a Customer Relationship Tool for WordPress that will be used primarly from the Wordpress Backend. I have custom post types: Contacts / People and Orders. The fields I've added using Advanced Custom Fields. What concerns me right now is that the UI of the post admin doesn't seem very adjustable. E.g., I want to select orders in a selection field and then assign them to a customer. I don't want to see any multiselect field on the customer afterwards but a nice table of all orders assigned. As well I want to record relationships between people, such as e.g. one person being the mail recepient of another one that is a firm. Then I would like to show a list for each person, with all mail addresses, be they form this person itself or from an assigned recipient.

**Idea**: I have seen some plugins that use an admin options page with a form to display and edit both list of posts and one specific post itself what seems to allow much more flexibility to create the UI. So I would like to make such an admin form to create, edit and display my custom post types. Yet I am totally stuck and lost in what and how to do it. I am still to much a noob to understand all the code from those plugins.

**Supperior question:** How do I create, display and edit a custom post type on an admin options page insted of the post admin page?

**My attempt:** I guess I need to break down this problem to junks like:

1. register a custom admin page
2. add a form to this custom admin page, that displays the fields from the custom post type with the desired UI design.
3. functionality to create a new post:

   - redirect to this custom admin page, if i click on a link / button to create a new post
   - make the form save the entered values to a new post
4. functionality to view and edit an existing post:

   - redirect to this custom admin page, if i click on an existing post to edit it
   - display values of the post's fields in the form and allowing me to change them and update the values.

Aspects 3 and 4 pose issues to me.

**I know those are different questions.** I list them here for you to see, what my brain twists are and will research and ask for those separately.

**Question:** To be able to approach that project (and ask the right further questions), first I need to know, if those are the right stepps to solve or if I should approach the project completely different. Please provide me with some enlightenment! Thanx a lot!

Comment: roxxistic - Welcome to WPSE. As you mentioned, you may get a little more traction with individual questions related to specific tasks/problems.